# Compiling python3.4 with a updated openssl library

Tags: python, compilation, openssl

I have an older version of Openssl that I no longer want to use with python3.4 programs. I have been using the following configure options

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I~/Downloads/openssl/1.0.1j/include" LDFLAGS="-L~/Downloads/openssl/1.0.1j/lib"
```

After compiling I print the openssl version from within a python program it will show the older version and not the one I have linked to above.

Are there other options I need to specify or do I need to alter setup.py?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` **before** running `./configure`. So, from the command line, (assuming you're using bash or similar):

```sh
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I~/Downloads/openssl/1.0.1j/include"
$ export LDFLAGS="-L~/Downloads/openssl/1.0.1j/lib"
$ ./configure
$ python3 setup.py make
$ sudo python3 setup.py install # assuming you have admin rights
```

Obviously, make sure you have successfully compiled openssl first, as just unzipping the source won't work. If you don't have admin access, or just choose to install everything in your home directory, I find it easier to create `~/lib` and `~/include` directories along with `~/bin` so everything can be stored in one place.